# CakePHP - how to give public authorization on the main page

Tags: cakephp

I set up the basic Authentication/Authorization set up, but a problem now is that every time I try to access the http://localhost:1234/, it requires user to login.

How/Where do I make the Auth->authorize("index") on the main page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside app_controller.php's beforeFilter():

```
 $this->Auth->authorize("display");
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

In the **beforeFilter()** of your controller

add the following piece of code

```
> $this->Auth->allow('actionname');
```

for suppose if I want to allow adding/registering of user without logging in then I would do like this in the **beforeFilter()** function of the users_controller.php file.

```
> $this->Auth->allow('add');
```

Comment: But that wasn't my question, and I already know about Auth's allow function, it was just not working with the main page on DocumentRoot.

Answer (score 0):

for cakephp 1.3 you have to do it now like this:

```
var $components = array(
   'Auth' => array(
   'authorize' => 'controller',
   'allowedActions' => array('index','**display**');
   )
);
```

And remember that you also can config a router:

```
Router::connect('/facebook', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => '**display**', 'facebook'));
```